# Web Deploy Package using Visual Studio 2013 does not create zip file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to Publish Web MVC application using the Web Deployment Package methodology. As per the documentation it is supposed to create a zip file at the specified location. But the zip file is not created for some reason. I have tried several times but there is no success. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you following the steps in the doc? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I am following these steps

Comment: Can you share your publishing profile? (.pubxml)

Comment: I have placed the profile as the answer as comment portion does not accept more than certain no of chars

Answer (score 0):

Here is the profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>C:\mytemp\DDP.MyWebSiteName.Web.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/MyWebSiteName</DeployIisAppPath>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="" />
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```